# Why is this bootstrap nav bar not showing correctly?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Why wont this work? I am sure i have set it up correctly although this is my first time using bootstrap. I am trying to use CDN distribution but I cant seem to get it to work. It currently just displays them as links as oppose to the nav bar that can be seen when used on other sites.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Required Meta Tags -->
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">


<title>Fictional Football Club</title>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="nav navbar-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Matches</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Table</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Squad</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tickets</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</nav>

<div class="container">

</div>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The navbar structure is not Bootstrap 4. Read the [Bootstrap 4 navbar docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/). Bootstrap 4 is now beta.

https://www.codeply.com/go/4GM7ligFGu

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light navbar-expand">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">News</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Matches</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Table</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Squad</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Tickets</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Ahhh cheers! It's what I get for not checking which version im using.